# WCF Change baseAddress

Tags: c#, wcf

Fairly novice to WCF and doing a simple project in VS2017 using the WCF Service Library project template. Name the project MyBlahService and create it.  Don't like the default file names Service1.cs and IService.cs so I rename them in the Solution Explorer.  This causes some automatic renaming of the IService1 interface and Service1 class. Running from VS started WCF Service Host and WCF Test Client and everything seemed to work OK. Poking around in App.config, I see an entry using 'Service1' like below and change it to the second entry below.

Was:

```
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MyBlahService/Service1/" />
    </baseAddresses>
```

Now:

```
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MyBlahService/MyBlahSvc/" />
    </baseAddresses>
```

This change broke the service until I went back to Service1.  I read all of the other posts that seemed relevant and noticed people had made similar changes, but they didn't explain how they did it.  I did a 'grep' of all files in the project and failed to find any other occurrence of 'Service1' so it is a real mystery to me how to use anything other than 'Service1'. Any help?

Comment: Is the problem solved? If my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer. If the problem is not solved, please let me know.

Comment: Did you try changing only the 'Service1' portion to something else in the default that looks like this: http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MyBlahService/Service1/  If you also have a problem, then it must be something special about the Design_Time_Addresses or the WCF test service host.  Possibly because I am using the 'Service Library' template and you are using something different?

Comment: This has nothing to do with baseaddress, the service library template I also use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with baseAddress. When you rename IService1 and Service1, you also need to modify the **service name** and **contract** in the configuration file.

Here is my demo:

[image]

I changed IService1 to ITest and I need to change the **contract** in the configuration file:

[image]

Change Service1 to Test:

[image]

[image]

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

**UPDATE**

Baseadress can be set at will:

```
<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Test" />

<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Test/Test" />

......
```

[image]

Comment: Your baseAddress still ends in 'Service1' - try changing that only and see if you break.  My question was, how to change that?  Other posts indicate people have done it, but they didn't say how.

Comment: The baseAddress can be set at will and there is no requirement, like this <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/" /> is also possible.

Comment: Mainly you need to modify the Contract and Service name in the configuration file after renaming IService1 and Service1.

Comment: Service name is the implementation class of the service interface, and contrat is the interface of the service.

Comment: If you have any questions, you can refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/endpoint-addresses

Comment: Maybe you can do me a favor and change your original baseAddress so it ends in 'Test' instead of 'Service1' and tell me if your project still works?  It might be some 'magic' thing with the 'magic' port 8733 and/or the Design_Time_Addresses?  Or maybe even something stupid the WcfSvcHost.exe program is doing. I will try one of your examples when I get on that computer tomorrow.  My service name, service interface and service interface implementation always had sanity so I'm sure it's something with the baseAddress setting.

Comment: Ok,I will post it.

Comment: I am accepting this answer, but see also my answer for some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I am accepting Ding Peng's answer because the effort put into it helped me solve the problem.  There is something 'magic' about either the Design_Time_Addresses and/or specifying the port.  You can put in other addresses easily if you leave both of those out.